# Sending dynamic SMS message body using Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using Twilio to [send an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) like so (relevant part of code shown):

```
require('Twilio.php'); 
$body ="some example message body text";
$account_sid = 'XXXXXXX'; 
$auth_token = 'YYYYY'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 
$client->account->messages->create(array(  
    'To' => $phone,
    'From' => "+15132592073", 
    'Body' => $body,   
));
```

The above works fine, however, if I change this to:

```
'Body' => "some example "+$test+" message body text";
```

The message body returns as "0".

I've also tried:

```
$myMessage ="some example "+$test+" message body text";
```

and then:

```
$client->account->messages->create(array(  
        'To' => $phone,
        'From' => "+15132592073", 
        'Body' => $myMessage,   
    ));
```

But this yields the same result ("0"). Note that:

```
$myMessage ="some example message body text";
```

this works fine also (i.e., same thing without the variable)

What am I missing here?

Comment: use . to concat strings in php

Comment: @Vanojx1 That was it...too much time working on javascript/jQuery

Comment: i know the feels ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
$body = "some example ". $test . " message body text";
```

Notice the concatenation operator '.' and not '+'.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Been spending too much time on javascript/jQuery. I'll accept the answer when I'm permitted.

Comment: Hey Pioneer, thank you for contributing to the Twilio-tagged community on StackOverflow. Can we send you a shirt to show our appreciation? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.